# Add array to a list of objects

Tags: c#, arrays, json, object, serialization

this is the class to create my json object

```
    public class RootObject
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string school { get; set; }
        public List<object> details{ get; set; }
    }
```

this is the way I'm creating a new object

```
        var obj = new RootObject();
        obj.name= "test";
        obj.id = "null";
        obj.school = "something else";
```

Then I am serializing the object using JavaScriptSerializer (this is working fine)
I need to add an array to this list of object "details" to get something like this:

```
{
  "name ":"test",
  "id":null,
  "school ":"something else",
  "details":["details1","detail2"]
}
```

I tried to add as string or element by element but without success. How can I solve this?

Comment: What did you try? What happened?

Comment: Are you initializing the List?

Comment: What are you having trouble with? Creating the list? Having the list be serialized? Deserializing the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the List:

```
obj.details = new List<object>();
```

Then to add data:

```
obj.details.Add("Details1");
obj.details.Add("Details2");
```

Comment: that's it! I totally forgot to initialize it...it happens sometimes, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I strongly suggest you just use Json.NET:

```
obj.details = new List<object>
{
    "details1", "details2"
};
```

Then, `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.Indented)` gives:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "id": "null",
  "school": "something else",
  "details": [
    "details1",
    "details2"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I have checked this before but I don't think I will need Json.NET for now but this works as well! Thanks